# Joomla - Display categories for more than one section from a menu

Tags: layout, joomla, blogs, categories

I am trying to add a menu item which will display the following:

a) The selected section names

b) all the categories and the lastest article in each category in a bout

something like

Section 1 
- Category 11 - latest article title and intro text 
- Category 12 - latest article title and intro text

Section 2
- Category 21 - latest article title and intro text 
- Category 22 - latest article title and intro text

I am familiar with the Category and section blog layouts, but have failed to find a solution to this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that showing more than two sections on a Joomla blog layout is not possible.

My solution was as follows using the excellent News Show Pro GK4 module (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/frontend-news/7738)

a) Create a module position just below the content block - since the News Show is a module, which has to be placed in a specific position

b) Create a blank dummy article - all the different menus will link to this article

c) Create the Joomla menu to the dummy page
- Add a class " hiddencontent" - without the quotes, also note the space in the class name so that it is an individual class
- set the page title in the menu options to match the name of the menu

d) Create and Configure the News Show Pro GK4 module for each section that I need to display together.

Therefore I end up with a "faux" multiple section blog layout

Hope this helps someone else, I almost lost all my hair doing it

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this was asked a very long time ago but it will probably help somebody else working on this in the future.

Joomla 2.5 or 1.5 doesn't have an option for this, however in Joomla 2.5 the easiest way of doing this is:

1. Mark all your articles as "Featured"
2. Go to your menu, and then change the type to "Featured articles"
3. It will ask you to select the categories you want to use, so select the ones you need
4. That's it!